# Pagination pagesize won't show in mobile view in antd Table react js

Tags: reactjs, frontend, antd

So in old version 4.xx of antd it worked fine always, i decided to migrate to latest version now pagination position works but i have setshowSizeChanger but wont show if i open or view site on mobile view

`pagination={{ position: ['topRight', 'bottomRight'], showSizeChanger: true }}`

this is prop I gave into Table component, pages are there but size changer hides in mobile, on desktop it works fine, any way to make size change true always for mobile and desktop

I have tried in old version it works fine for both mobile and desktop and also I tried a clean project with Table component and data but issue is same on new project too with newer version,
any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have inspected the code, and I found that it's because when the screen is smaller than 576px, the pageSizeChanger will become display none.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .ant-pagination .ant-pagination-options {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Hence, I just override the antd css although its says not to override. Here's my code in `global.css`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .ant-pagination .ant-pagination-options {
        padding-top: 10px;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey sorry for being late but i just tried your css and it worked beautifully! many thanks for it, although i removed padding-top now its properly aligned with page numbers in mobile view thanks!